# Android - No gestures or touches detected for custom LinearLayout

Tags: android, touch-event, gesturedetector

I am trying to create a custom LinearLayout view (called myView) that has its own GestureDetector for flings. This LinearLayout is placed in the main layout, and I want to detect a fling/touch on this custom LinearLayout.

I have tried following all the advice on these forums, including oveeriding the touch, dispatch and intercept methods. However, I'm not even able to get any of these methods to even fire (I am not seeing my debug output). Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong? Below are the relevant code snippets.

The custom LinearLayout:

```
public class MyView extends LinearLayout {

    private final TextView mText;
    private final ImageView mImage;

    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Debug";

    public CardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view, this);

        mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text);
        mImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_picture);

        setupGestureDetector();

    }

 // Set up GestureDetector
    private void setupGestureDetector() {

        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {            
            //@Override
            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
                float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Detected Fling!");
                return true;
            }

        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        // TODO - delegate the touch to the gestureDetector 
        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Intercepted touch");
        return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        // TODO - delegate the touch to the gestureDetector 
        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Dispatched touch");
        return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        // TODO - delegate the touch to the gestureDetector 
        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Detected on Touch");
        return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

}
```

The main activity:

```
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Opine";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Started my app");


    }

}
```

And the XML for the custom LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/border">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/my_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/my_picture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the XML of the main activity's view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <com.pratikthaker.opine.MyView
        android:id="@+id/view0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use Log.d for debug, not Log.e

Comment: True - I was using Log.e just so that the red sticks out..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not even registering your `mGestureDetector` to the `LinearLayout` to get some respose to `onTouch` thus giving you no result from the Log.

**Solution**

Register it in the `onTouchListener` of your LinearLayout using its `MotionEvent` parameter to get some response upon touching the layout.

**Sample**

```
private void setupGestureDetector() {

    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {            

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
            float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Detected Fling!");
            return true;
        }
    });

    this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

**another problem:**

```
<com.pratikthaker.opine.MyView
    android:id="@+id/view0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Since you are wrapping its content then there is no way the MyView will be touch, you will rather touch the relative layout instead. you need to use `match_parent` attribute for it.

Comment: he is calling mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event); in two places

Comment: so he doesn't need setOnTouchListener at all

Comment: @pskink yea, now the problem is that he wraps the width and hieght of the custom view.

Comment: @pskink if there no child view then it will default to 0

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin - You were right about the wrap_content. I set match_parent and I am registering a touch. However, right after that I am getting a NullPointerException: | E/InputEventReceiver(32532): Exception dispatching input event. |
08-14 
E/MessageQueue-JNI(32532): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback |

E/MessageQueue-JNI(32532): java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @PratikThaker you need to debug it. you class is not that fairly long. it would be easy, At least we solve your problem.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin - Okay, will do. Appreciate the help with solving this issue. :)

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin - Okay, this is weird. I figured out the NullPointer was because I was not calling the function that was initializing the mGestureDetector. However, once I enabled that, I am again not seeing any output for the touch events! I'm confused...

Comment: I even removed the whole gestureDetector code and am just trying to print out a debug line in the onTouchEvent and I don't see it. I'll continue to try to get that to work first. Let me know if you know what the issue might be.

Comment: @PratikThaker post the code and add commend where is the NPE located.

Comment: Actually you know what, I'm not getting any Log output from that MyView class! I put a log in my constructor and it's not showing up! I think the issue is that I am not seeing the log output. Will try to figure that out or I'll post another question about that if I cannot. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @PratikThaker btw make sure you have the three contructor on it. in your custom view. and try to log all of them. You are welcome.